# Running a php function when dropbox on change event and returns a table from the php function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, html-select

I have the following code for a dropbox;

```
 <select name="Symptom" id="Symptomid" onchange="LSC()">
```

On change in the dropbox i want to run the following php code;

```
<?php
$data = array();
{
  $symptoms_name = $_POST['Symptom'];
  $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT name,description , comments
  FROM symptoms WHERE symptoms.name ='$symptoms_name'") or             

    die(mysql_error());     

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
        $data[] = $row1;
    }
}
?>
<?php
if($data){
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>description</td>
        <td>comments</td>
    </tr>

<?php
    if($data){
        foreach($data as $sy){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $sy['name']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $sy['description']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $sy['comments']; ?> </td>

    </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
<?php
}

?>


</table>
}

and display this table under the dropbox on the original html .
```

I think we have to run a java script which will call the php function and retun the table to the original html.

```
Kindly assist, I know we have to use ajax.

Regards

Azhar
```

Answer (score 0):

sorted,

see this has a similar problem

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Regards

Azhar